# magento: How do configure total quantity rules for shopping cart at checkout?

Tags: magento, checkout

I have searched far and wide but cannot find the correct answer.

I have an online shop to sell wine and sell by the bottle. However I can only ship in multiple of 6. i.e. 6, 12, 18, 24, and so on in any SKU combination.

I have tried Config->Inventory->"Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart" it works for individual product but not for total quantity at checkout.

http://www.finewineimports.com.au/all.html

Is there an way (via an extension, code or admin) to configure the rule during check out such that the total quantity regardless of the different SKUs has to be multiple of 6?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Config->Inventory and set "Enable Qty Increments" to Yes. A "Qty Increments" field will appear below that. Enter your multiple there (in your case, 6). Save your settings.

Comment: This is only works for individual product - single SKU. I would like the total quantity in the shopping cart to be multiple of 6. e.g. SKU1 qty = 2, SKU2 qty = 2 and SKU3 qty = 2. Total is 6 so valid. However if SKU3 was say 3 the total in cart is 7, this should be rejected.